# Is there a way for Ansible mysql_variables module to set variable persistent?

Tags: mysql, variables, ansible, mysql-variables

I have an Ansible playbook with this task..

```
---
- name: Set mysql_variable
  mysql_variables:
    variable: mysql_variable
    value: 2000
- name: Reload MySQL
  service:
    name: mysql
    state: restarted
    enabled: yes
```

the 1st task sets the variable to desired state, I can verify.. but it's not persistent. When 2nd task reloads mysql service, the variable gets set to default value.

How to set this variable persistent with Ansible on the target node??

Comment: Which variable are you trying to set ? How would you make your modification survive reboot without using ansible ? It's hard to answer without knowing the exact variable, but chances are you need to add that to your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: variable is `group_concat_max_len`

Comment: See this other answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/346866/set-group-concat-max-len-permanently-mysql-config. You can use the lineinfile module for that. You can both set this and the var if you want to avoid reboot while still making sure the value will be as you wish on the next restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [community.mysql.mysql_variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_variables_module.html) module supports this with `mode: persist`, assuming you have MySQL 8.0+ and are setting a dynamic variable:

```yaml
- name: Configure a MySQL dynamic setting
  community.mysql.mysql_variables:
    variable: "binlog_expire_logs_seconds"
    value: "{{ '1w' | community.general.to_seconds | int }}"
    mode: persist
  become: true
```

The equivalent [`SET PERSIST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) statement:

```bash
$ sudo mysql --execute "SET persist binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 604800;"
```

Show any variables persisted to `mysqld-auto.cnf` ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-persisted-variables-table.html)):

```bash
$ sudo mysql --execute "SELECT * FROM performance_schema.persisted_variables;"
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME                   | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| binlog_expire_logs_seconds      | 604800         |
| max_allowed_packet              | 268435456      |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

#### Caveats

- MySQL 5.7 doesn't support this statement (and it's EOL).
- Some variables still need to be updated in the appropriate `my.cnf` or `mysqld.cnf` with the `lineinfile` module.

  Look for errors like:

  `Variable 'innodb_log_file_size' is a read only variable`

  `Variable 'bind_address' is a read only variable`